# Your account is not enabled for Microsoft Forms

Tags: office-365, microsoft-forms

I have the following licenses inside Office 365, including Microsoft Forms:-

[image: thumbnail image 1 of blog post titled]

Now I can access the Form home page and create new Forms as follow:-

[image: thumbnail image 2 of blog post titled]

but when someone share a Form with me and i click on the form link inside the invitation email, i got this error:-

[image: thumbnail image 3 of blog post titled]

so what could be the reason?

Comment: Was the license only added very recently for you?  The forum post at https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-forms/your-account-is-not-enabled-for-microsoft-forms-error/m-p/283264 seems to suggest it might be helpful to either sign out/back-in to Microsoft 365 and check again, or to wait some time (approx 12 to 24 hours) for your login token to expire.

Comment: @DRVR you are correct, the license was granted to me recently.. today when i login to the form , i can access it.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen when the licence for Microsoft Forms has only just been assigned very recently.  It appears the resolution is often to either sign-in/out of the Microsoft 365 account, or simply wait (up to approximately half a day, or a full day).

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to a user and the problem was that they were bouncing between their company account and an education institution's MS account in their browser. I had them log out and forget both accounts, restart, then log back in to the company account only and everything worked.